# Android: onReceiveResult is not triggered

Tags: android, methods, service, handler

I'm trying to get some data from a `Service` that gets an address from coordinates. I followed the step by step official android tutorial about this (http://developer.android.com/training/location) but i'm stuck. I'm sending the data from the `Service` class to the `Activity` using the `send` method but the `onReceiveResult` method doesn't seem to trigger. Here's my `Service` class:

```
public class FetchAddressIntentService extends IntentService {

    protected ResultReceiver mReceiver;

    public FetchAddressIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public FetchAddressIntentService() {
        super("FetchAddressIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        String errorMessage = "";

        // Get the location passed to this service through an extra.
        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA);
        mReceiver = new ResultReceiver(new Handler());
        List < Address > addresses = null;

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1); //we want 1 result
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.service_not_available);
            Log.e("TAG", errorMessage, ioException);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.invalid_lat_long_used);
            Log.e("TAG", errorMessage + ". " + "Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude = " + location.getLongitude(), illegalArgumentException);
        }

        if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
            if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
                errorMessage = getString(R.string.no_address_found);
                Log.e("TAG", errorMessage);
            }
            deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage);
        } else {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            ArrayList < String > addressFragments = new ArrayList < String > ();

            for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
            }
            Log.i("TAG", getString(R.string.address_found) + ": " + addressFragments.get(0));
            deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT, TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"), addressFragments));
        }
    }

    private void deliverResultToReceiver(int resultCode, String message) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY, message);
        mReceiver.send(resultCode, bundle);
    }
}
```

And the relevant part of my `Activity`:

```
class AddressResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
    public AddressResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

        mAddressOutput = resultData.getString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY);
        Log.i("address", mAddressOutput);
        address.setText(mAddressOutput);

        if (resultCode == Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT) {
            Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this, getString(R.string.address_found),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added answer, hope this help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create receiver in Activity

```
private AddressResultReceiver mReceiver;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler());
    mReceiver.setReceiver(this);
}
```

and pass to Intent service

```
public void onStarService() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent("SOME_COMMAND_ACTION", null, this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);
    intent.putExtra("RECEIVER", mReceiver);
    startService(intent);
}
```

and in FetchAddressIntentService

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    final ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("RECEIVER");
/// your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
mReceiver = new ResultReceiver(new Handler());
```

Replace it with this:

```
mReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.RECEIVER);
```

The problem is that you're creating a new `ResultReceiver` instead of using the one that is presumably passed in as an `Intent` *extra* from this code:

```
protected void startIntentService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, mLastLocation);
    startService(intent);
}
```

So, just use the one passed in as an *extra* in the `Intent`, and it should work.